# jQuery to filter the result of Ajax call to return column data in an array

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a list of records as a result of an Ajax call:

```
$data = [{0,name,adress,date, number1},
         {1,name,adress,date, number1},
         {2,name,adress,date, number2},
         {3,name,adress,date, number3}....];
```

I want to filter the unique numbers (number1, number2.....) with date and store them in a list.

Comment: those are not valid objects in the array. Show valid data as well as what research you have done or code you attempted to solve this yourself

Comment: Also *"I want to"* is not a question. Take a few minutes to review [ask]

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

This example solves the issue if the resulting data is JSON formatted, if it isn't then you could do it by index.

```js
var data = [
  {id: 0, name: 'chris', address: 'addy0', date: '02/15/1923', number: 5046},
  {id: 1, name: 'tim', address: 'addy1', date: '02/15/1913', number: 5342},
  {id: 2, name: 'mike', address: 'addy2', date: '02/15/1953', number: 2454563},
  {id: 3, name: 'john', address: 'addy3', date: '02/15/1923', number: 24354}
];

console.log(filter(data));

function filter(arr) {
  var f = []
  return arr.filter(function(n) {
    //this line is filtering by date attribute on each element of the array
    return f.indexOf(n.date) == -1 && f.push(n.date);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for not naming the array `$data`

Comment: @TomNijs yeah i didn't think adding to jquery globals was a great plan ;)  lol hopefully this helps them...although really more information is needed before any real answer could be provided.